# Startup Errors for Version 5.2 of WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have downloaded the latest version of wso2 identity server (5.2). However during the startup process I am getting the following errors.

```
    [2016-10-26 09:50:27,563]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/wso2].File[D:\wso2is-5.2.0\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\webapps\wso2.war]
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.



java.security.KeyStoreException: failed to extract any certificates or private keys - maybe bad password?

[2016-10-26 09:50:29,074] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine} -
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.SSL.<init>(SSL.java:154)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.SSLClient.<init>(SSLClient.java:60)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.HttpSecureProtocol.<init>(HttpSecureProtocol.java:55)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.ssl.EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.<init>(EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:94)
        at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.<init>(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:84)
        ... 113 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:127)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:118)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<clinit>(TrustMaterial.java:108)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyMaterial
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.SSL.<init>(SSL.java:154)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.SSLClient.<init>(SSLClient.java:60)
```

It is a vanilla version of the server and I haven't made any kind of configuration changes. I am running on JDK 1.8. Can someone tell me what the resolution will be.  I tried including "not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.10.jar" and that didnt help.

Regards
Ranjith Madhavan

Comment: What is your OS? Is that Oracle JDK?

Comment: Can you try to extract the zip again and see? Maybe the pack wasn't extracted properly.

Comment: I have tried against both Ubuntu as well as windows. Extracted the Zip file multpile times too. And yes it is oracle JDK. I have also downloaded the zip file twice and validated the checksum too. All looks ok to me except that there is this startup error.

Comment: Can you try with [JCE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) enabled if you haven't done already?

Comment: tried that just now. Used local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar from the jce_policy-8 which i downloaded form the Oracle site. still i am getting the same error. Which  java do you use. Oracle or OpenJDK?

Comment: Oracle should work.

Comment: My version of java was `java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)` Once i upgraded to `java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)` the error seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this exception, it was due to the fact that i donot have /lib/security/cacerts and /lib/security/jssecacerts in my jre.